# Are moles effective at controlling Japanese beetle grubs?

Tags: pests, pest-control, insects, permaculture

My garden is under assault this summer by Japanese beetles from above, and moles from below. From my research, Japanese beetles lay their eggs a few inches underground, and moles are voracious insectivores.

I've been hand-picking the beetles every few hours but as they're nearly constantly getting it on this time of year, I'm sure they've already laid plenty of eggs for next year's crop. I notice that the moles' surface feeding tunnels seem to be concentrated more heavily near the infested plants. Is this a coincidence or can I count on them to gobble up the eggs and grubs?

I don't love how the moles push up the lawn, but I can tolerate pushing the turf back down every morning if I knew that they were cleaning up the grubs underneath.

Answer (score 2):

You won’t love the Moles after you have ruined a few lawnmower blades.

I don’t recommend encouraging a mole infestation. If you allow a population to really get established, your lawn will be the source of other people’s problems.

I think it better to plant something the grubs won’t eat. I happen to like like Dutch White Clover. The grubs don’t eat it and it enriches the soil.

Comment: Very true but once planted it is very difficult to remove

Answer (score 2):

One source I've read (wish I could remember where it was so I could reference it here) stated that a typical mole's diet is 75% earthworms and 25% grubs of all kinds, so your moles are probably going after the worms in your yard.

Answer (score 0):

The moles are likely consuming the larvae, even though they larvae are sort of little, and with that many of them, it could have been what has attractedthem to reside and dine there. Moles arent usually bothersome, & aereate and blend the soil etc., just be little careful when walking.